# G is a group. $g_1,g_2 \in G$. $H_1,H_2 \leq G$. Show the 2 statements are equivalent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

G is a group. $g_1,g_2\in G$. $H_1,H_2\leq G$. Show the 2 statements are equivalent.
1. $g_1H_1 \subset g_2H_2$.
2. $H_1 \subset H_2 \space and \space g_2 ^ {-1} g_1 \in H_2$

This should be an easy problem. I find $2 \Rightarrow 1$ is rather trivial to prove. However, I'm having difficulty proving the converse. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $g_1H_1 \subset g_2H_2$.
Since $1\in H_1$, we have $g_1=g_1 1\in g_1H_1 \subset g_2H_2$.
Hence $g_1=g_2h$ for some $h\in H_2$.
This means that $g^{-1}_2g_1=h\in H_2$.

Let $x\in H_1$.
Then $g_1x=g_2 y$ for some $y\in H_2$.
Hence $x=g^{-1}_1g_2 y$.
Since $g^{-1}_2g_1\in H_2$, $g^{-1}_1g_2=(g^{-1}_2g_1)^{-1}\in H_2$.
We conclude that $x\in H_2$.